# Can we shift widget between the cells of a table widget

Tags: qt

I've created a a widget in which I've placed two buttons using a layout and placed it inside a table widget's cell. The thing is that I'm changing the size of the table and I want to shift the placement of the widget without deleting them and re-initializing them from the beginning because I already assigned them actions on click (I think that the application would crash in this situation)

Code:

```
btn = new QPushButton[horzHeaders.size()];
btn[j].setParent(ui->tableWidget);
btn[j].setIcon(QIcon("./save.png"));
btn[j].setVisible(true);
btn_Load = new QPushButton[horzHeaders.size()];
btn_Load[j].setParent(ui->tableWidget);
btn_Load[j].setIcon(QIcon("./upload.png"));
btn_Load[j].setVisible(true);
lay = new QHBoxLayout[horzHeaders.size()];
lay[j].addWidget(&btn[j]);
lay[j].addWidget(&btn_Load[j]);
QWidget *w = new QWidget[horzHeaders.size()];
w[j].setLayout(&lay[j]);
ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(j,vertHeaders.size() - 1, &w[j]);
```

Comment: You can re-implement resizeEvent of your MainWindow(or whatever widget tableWidget is being placed inside) and use setCellWidget the same way you did in snippet of code you provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add and remove widgets from a layout anytime you want

```
QWidget *widget = new QWidget();
QPushButton *button = new QPushButton();
QHBoxLayout *Hbox = new QHBoxLayout();
QVBoxLayout *Vbox= new QVBoxLayout();
Hbox->addWidget(button);
// use it till the window is resized
//and then check with an if-statement if the window is resized or not
Hbox->removeWidget(button); // remove from the button from layout
layout()->removeAt(widget); //remove the widget's current layout
Vbox->addWidget(button);  // add button widget to vertical layout
widget->setLayout(Vbox); // Give it a new layout
widget->setLayout(Vbox);
```

If this didn't answer your question then ask in the comments.